# How can I send just one alert with kapacitor if something is down?

Tags: alert, influxdb, kapacitor

I have the following stick script

```
stream
|from()
    .measurement('mymetric_value')
|deadman(1.0, 10s)
    .message('service is down!')
    .log('/tmp/alerts.log')
    .email('myemail@company.com')
```

It send an alert every 10 seconds that the service is down. 
How can I set it to send only one?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There is a property method `stateChangesOnly()` on Alert nodes in a TICKscript that will only issue an alert if the state of the alert changes. Your script would look like this:

```
stream
|from()
    .measurement('mymetric_value')
|deadman(1.0, 10s)
    .message('service is down!')
    .log('/tmp/alerts.log')
    .email('myemail@company.com')
    .stateChangesOnly()
```

See the [kapacitor documentation on stateChangeOnly()](http://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.0/nodes/alert_node/#statechangesonly) for more information.